# JQueryMobile Button/Listview Overlap

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, button

In my experience, having a `<ul>` right above or below a button `<a data-role="button">..</a>` causes them to overlap. My workaround is to generously use `<br>`'s, but this seems like a broken workflow.

Does anyone know a fix to this overlap issue?

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbef8/) demonstrating my problem.

Here is the code used in the fiddle:

```
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>World</li>
        </ul>
        <a data-role="button" href="#">Give me my space!</a>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
            <li>Boring</li>
            <li>workaround</li>
        </ul>
        <BR>
        <a data-role="button" href="#">Give me my space!</a>
    </div>
```

Update: I played around a bit more, and making the listview inset fixed the overlap. Nonetheless, I would like a way to avoid overlapping without inset if anyone knows how!
[New JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbef8/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an incorrect margin override in jQuery Mobile's CSS.

You can work around it by specifying:

```
.ui-content .ui-listview, .ui-panel-inner .ui-listview {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

However, this may conflict with other jQuery Mobile widgets (unless the margin override is a bug to begin with).

You can see the results in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbef8/8/).

Comment: Nice! I'll use this and keep my eye out for any side effects on other widgets